# Getting rid of two ; characters only if they contain only blanks, with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, osx-yosemite

I have a file with plenty of `;` characters that act as a delimiter/separator. At some places, they are redundant. There are character sequences that are of the forms `;;`, `;;;`, `; ;`, etc. Is there a way to get rid of one of those semicolons and what they have in between only if there is nothing in between them other than blanks?

In other words, I want to convert `text; ; text; text;` to `text; text; text;` by replacing either one of the forms I mentioned above with just one `;`. I thought of using `sed`, but if another command can do the job, I'm of course ok with it.

I am using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: `Is there a way to get rid of one of those semicolons and what they have in between only if there is nothing in between them other than blanks` - They must be an atomic block of one or more characters,, that act as a unitary operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/;\( *;\)\{1,\}/;/g'
```

An alternative would be

```
sed 's/\(; *\)\{1,\}/; /g'
```

With GNU sed, you could use `\+` instead of `\{1,\}` instead of `\+`. You could also use extended regular expressions (`-E` on BSD sed, `-r` with Gnu sed) for a more readable regular expression:

```
sed -E 's/;( *;)+/;/g'
sed -E 's/(; *)+/;/g'
```

The difference between the two forms is that the second one will always make sure that there is a space after a semicolon. (Neither fixes spaces before the first semicolon in a series. Add a `*` to the beginning of the patterns if that's what you want.)

Comment: `\+` won't work on OSX, which has BSD sed. Use `\{1,\}` instead.

Comment: @Wintermute: Doesn't bsd sed have -E? Maybe it would be more readable to use EREs.

Comment: `sed -E 's/(; *)+/; /g'` should work, yes. Of course, GNU sed won't accept that anymore, but OP may not care.

Comment: And for GNU sed that would be `sed -r 's/(; *)+/; /g'` (just for the record).

Comment: @Wintermute Since when doesn't GNU sed accept that? It's not documented any more, but afaik it continues to work fine.

Comment: The second version did the trick, thank you both :)
Can you explain what `(; *)+` exactly chooses? I don't know what `(` does.

Comment: @rici Today I learned that GNU sed accepts `-E`. That's what I get for reading the documentation. >.< Btw, I think recent versions of BSD sed also accept `-r` for compatibility with GNU sed. I'm not sure how recent the version is that comes with Mac OS X, though.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate: parentheses define a group, so `(; *)+` means "one or more repetitions of (a semicolon followed by zero or more spaces)"

Comment: @Wintermute: OS X `sed`, as of 10.10.3, does _not_ accept `-r`.